# Can you use image without saving it to file on Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement camera app with certain features. I need to take a picture using phone's camera and then manipulate that image. However, I don't need to save the picture to the file, I only need to get some "data" from the picture. Is there a way to take picture and then immediately load it as bitmap or do I need to at least save it, read it and then delete it.

I read this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html, but saving and deleting images seems heavy on processor, so I'd like to avoid it if I can. Ty

Comment: RAM available to your app is limited so you definitely want to save the image to a file and then parse it by small parts via an InputStream.

Comment: using intents, no, because the size of the bundle limits the size of the image that can be passed back. Using the camera directly, sure.

Answer (score 0):

As [Saiteja Prasadam notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38835947/115145), if you skip `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, you will get a thumbnail `Bitmap` back via `getExtra("data")`.

Beyond that, you can work with the camera APIs directly (e.g., `android.hardware.Camera`).

You could try creating a `ContentProvider` that supports writing to a memory buffer instead of a file, then use a `content:` `Uri` pointing to that provider in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Getting this to work correctly, and without fragmenting your heap space, may be difficult or impossible.

Overall, bear in mind that you might not have heap space for a full-resolution image anyway. I do not know what "some "data" from the picture" means, exactly, but if it depends upon loading the whole image into RAM, you are going to have challenges implementing that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant API documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback)

```
void takePicture (Camera.ShutterCallback shutter, 
            Camera.PictureCallback raw, 
            Camera.PictureCallback postview, 
            Camera.PictureCallback jpeg)
```

shutter: the callback for image capture moment, or null
raw: the callback for raw (uncompressed) image data, or null
postview: callback with postview image data, may be null
jpeg: the callback for JPEG image data, or null

Answer (score -1):

**Start Intent**

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

**Activity Result**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
    }  
}
```

> Note: This thumbnail image from "data" might be good for an icon, but not a lot more. Dealing with a full-sized image takes a bit more work.

Comment: "Note: This thumbnail image from "data" might be good for an icon, but not a lot more. Dealing with a full-sized image takes a bit more work.", according to the link I provided.

Comment: Didn't realise that, Looks like there is no direct way to get the full-size image. You are forced to save it to a file.

Comment: If "you are forced to save it to a file" then how does WhatsApp handle that when directly taking and sending an image? I can't really imagine there is no better way...